# My CSV files are not being assigned to the correct Key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def read_prices(tikrList):
#read each file and get the price list dictionary 
  def getPriceDict():
    priceDict = {}
    TLL = len(tikrList)
    for x in range(0,TLL):
      with open(tikrList[x] + '.csv','r') as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        for column in csvReader:
          priceDict[column[0]] = float(column[1])
    return priceDict

#populate the final dictionary with the price dictionary from the previous function
  def popDict():
    combDict = {}
    TLL = len(tikrList)
    for x in range(0,TLL):
      for y in tikrList:
        combDict[y] = getPriceDict()
    return combDict
  return(popDict())

print(read_prices(['GOOG','XOM','FB']))
```

What is wrong with the code is that when I return the final dictionary the key for GOOG,XOM,FB is represnting the values for the FB dictionary only.

As you can see with this output:

```
{'GOOG': {'2015-12-31': 104.660004, '2015-12-30': 106.220001},
 'XOM': {'2015-12-31': 104.660004, '2015-12-30': 106.220001},
 'FB': {'2015-12-31': 104.660004, '2015-12-30': 106.220001}
```

I have 3 different CSV files but all of them are just reading the CSV file for FB.

I want to apologize ahead of time if my code is not easy to read or doesn't make sense. I think there is an issue with storing the values and returning the priceDict in the getPriceDict function but I cant seem to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `for x in range(0,TLL):` - what does this outer loop in `popDict` do?

Comment: The question can input any amount of test CSV files, I just have 3 -'GOOG','XOM,'FB' however my professor can input as many as he wants. So I take the length on the list of how many files he wants to input and I run a loop so I understand how many times I need to add a new key value dictionary pair for each new stock ticker name.

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mcve].

Comment: Have you made any attempt at debugging? Have you printed/examined anything in your functions to try to find what is wrong and what is right? If you are using an IDE it probably has debugging facilities - now is the time to learn that - although printing can be pretty useful. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is classwork I won't provide a solution but I'll point a few things out.

- You have defined three functions - two are defined *inside* the third. While structuring functions like that can make sense for some problems/solutions I don't see any benefit in your solution. It seems to make it more complicated.
- The two inner functions don't have any parameters, you might want to refactor them so that when they are called you pass them the information they need. One advantage of a function is to encapsulate an idea/process into a *self-contained* code block that doesn't rely on resources *external* to itself. This makes it easy to test so you know that the function works and you can concentrate on other parts of the code.

This piece of your code doesn't make much sense - it never uses `x` from the outer loop:

```
...
    for x in range(0,TLL):
      for y in tikrList:
        combDict[y] = getPriceDict()
```

When you iterate over a list the iteration will stop after the last item and it [will iterate over the items themselves](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) - no need to iterate over numbers to access the items: don't do `for i in range(thelist): print(thelist[i])`

```
>>> tikrList = ['GOOG','XOM','FB']
>>> for name in tikrList:
...     print(name)

GOOG
XOM
FB
>>>
```

---

When you read through a tutorial or the documentation, don't just look at the examples - read and understand the text  .

Comment: Personally, I think you are over-enginnering this thing.  Can you not just download this data, dynamically, from the web?  If that's an option,post back with a 'YES' and I will share a script with you, that downloads historical equity time series data from Yahoo Finance.